# XINU - Need help understanding a system call - getstk.c

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am having trouble conceptually understanding what is going on towards the end of this system call, and why. I understand the getstk.c method returns the highest memory address of available space, but don't understand what some of the code is doing. Some clarity on this would be great. The areas of code I don't fully understand are emphasized in asterisks.

```
/* getstk.c - getstk */

#include <xinu.h>

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  getstk  -  Allocate stack memory, returning highest word address
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
char    *getstk(
          uint32        nbytes          /* size of memory requested     */
        )
{
        intmask mask;                   /* saved interrupt mask         */
        struct  memblk  *prev, *curr;   /* walk through memory list     */
        struct  memblk  *fits, *fitsprev; /* record block that fits     */

        mask = disable();
        if (nbytes == 0) {
                restore(mask);
                return (char *)SYSERR;
        }

        nbytes = (uint32) roundmb(nbytes);      /* use mblock multiples */

        prev = &memlist;
        curr = memlist.mnext;
        fits = NULL;
        fitsprev = NULL;  /* to avoid a compiler warning */

        while (curr != NULL) {                  /* scan entire list     */
                if (curr->mlength >= nbytes) {  /* record block address */
                        fits = curr;            /*   when request fits  */
                        fitsprev = prev;
                }
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->mnext;
        }

        if (fits == NULL) {                     /* no block was found   */
                restore(mask);
                return (char *)SYSERR;
        }
        if (nbytes == fits->mlength) {          /* block is exact match */
                fitsprev->mnext = fits->mnext;
        **} else {                                /* remove top section   */
                fits->mlength -= nbytes;
                fits = (struct memblk *)((uint32)fits + fits->mlength);
        }**
        memlist.mlength -= nbytes;
        restore(mask);
        **return (char *)((uint32) fits + nbytes - sizeof(uint32));**
}
```

The struct memblk can be found here:

```
struct  memblk  {           /* see roundmb & truncmb    */
    struct  memblk  *mnext;     /* ptr to next free memory blk  */
    uint32  mlength;        /* size of blk (includes memblk)*/
    };
extern  struct  memblk  memlist;    /* head of free memory list */
```

Why are they returning the fits + nbytes - sizeof(uint32)? Why are they casting fits(a struct) to type uint32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (nbytes == fits->mlength) {          /* block is exact match */
            fitsprev->mnext = fits->mnext;
    **} else {                                /* remove top section   */
            fits->mlength -= nbytes;
            fits = (struct memblk *)((uint32)fits + fits->mlength);
    }**
    memlist.mlength -= nbytes;
    restore(mask);
    **return (char *)((uint32) fits + nbytes - sizeof(uint32));**
```

If a perfect fit is found, the block is just removed from the free list. If a larger block is found, the block is split into two blocks: a free block `nbytes` smaller than the original block (`fits->mlength -= nbytes`); and an allocated block of `nbytes` starting after the new free block (`fits = (struct memblk *)((uint32)fits + fits->mlength)`), to be returned by the function.

> Why are they returning the fits + nbytes - sizeof(uint32)? Why are they casting fits(a struct) to type uint32?

Since the stack grows down in this case, the function returns a pointer to the top of the stack, which is the word at the end of the allocated block, i.e.:

```
(uint32)fits /* start of allocated block */ + nbytes /* size of allocated block */ - sizeof(uint32) /* size of a word */
```

The cast to `(uint32)` is to use integer arithmetic instead of pointer arithmetic, otherwise `fits+1` would yield a pointer that points `sizeof(struct memblk)` beyond `fits`. Casting to `(char *)` would perhaps be more idiomatic.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why this is done:

fits = (struct memblk *)((uint32)fits + fits->mlength);

The return value is still throwing me off as well :(

Comment: @blackdemon619: `fits` points to the bottom of the allocated block. When we find a larger block, that block is split in two, the second part starts at `(uint32)fits + fits->mlength`.